# Replace using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to make a function that break lines from a string.

eg.: "1. " -> "\n1. "

so i could write a code like this

```
string Input = "1. First option";
Input += "2. Second option";
Input += "3. Third option";

Output = WriteMenu(Input);
```

and get a string like this

```
"1. First option
\n2. Second option
\n3. Third option"
```

The pattern will always be [number][dot][whitespace].
It's not a problem if the first option came with new line.

Comment: So just to be clear (because it seems the current answers have overlooked this): you **don't** want a CRLF in front of the `1.`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this guy a shot

```
Input = Regex.Replace(Input, @"(?<!^)(\d+\.)", "\n$1")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("(\\d+\\.\\s)");
String replaced = rgx.Replace(Input, Environment.NewLine + "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter expression like this would work too:

```
Regex.Replace(Input, @"(?!^)\d+\.", "\n$0")
```